# Assistance with ifelse formula

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I'm new to R in general and find that I get stuck on the syntax of ifelse a lot.

Here is an expression that I have written, it runs without error but doesn't seem to actually do anything:

```
AutoRenewals$LTA_year <- ifelse(AutoRenewals$Unity_LTA_Year == "2019" & AutoRenewals$LTA_year == NA,"2019",AutoRenewals$LTA_year)
```

Effectively what I want is to say that if a row(s) within the column of LTA_year is blank (NA) and the string value of 2019 is present in Unity_LTA_Year then I want LTA_Year column to show 2019, otherwise keep the original value of LTA_Year in place.

Comment: `== NA` doesn't work for testing if something is `NA`, use `is.na` for that. (The idea is that `NA == NA` should return `NA` because who knows if two different missing values are equal or not. Similarly `2019 == NA` returns `NA` because maybe that `NA` is 2019, maybe it isn't.)

Comment: Your code will probably work fine if you replace `AutoRenewals$LTA_year == NA` with `is.na(AutoRenewals$LTA_year)`. I'm sure there is a FAQ about it somewhere, but I'm not finding it right now.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for answering, wish I'd had you 20 days ago as I am sure your suggestion would have helped. I managed to attack it a different way in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this by removing all values that were not 2019 from the dataframe, then merged that dataframe with the main one followed by this expression: AutoRenewals$LTA_year <- ifelse(is.na(AutoRenewals$LTA_year), AutoRenewals$Unity_LTA_Year, AutoRenewals$LTA_year)

Don't know if anyone else will ever run into a similar situation, but hopefully if you do this can help.